# How is server blazor supposed to use bundled scoped css files from Razor Class Libraries?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

When you have a server side blazor app and you reference a razor class library directly (at the moment I am using dotnet5) it seems to automatically add the /_content/.bundle.scp.css by adding an @import to the .styles.css.  This appears to work well enough at least in debug just by adding the reference and hitting F5.

I see conflicting documentation adding the links manually in many places and they are generally being added in the head as links, not as an @import.  I am guessing this is maybe something that has changed since core3.  I also have not figured out where the bundled files are supposed to "live" while you are still developing, when you publish you end up with a \wwwroot_content folder, but a development that appears not to exist on the filesystem and actually be mapped onto the \obj folders of the individual RCLs.

In the app I am currently working on the razor class libraries are loaded at run time, so this does not work automatically, for the time being I have the bundles referenced as individual links programmatically added in the head of the _host.cshtml after I copy them from the individual RCLs' obj<BuildFolder>\net5.0\ as that seems to be the only place they exist on disk.  I am also serving them with an app.UseStaticFiles out of another folder since I am still unclear on how the inbuilt folders are meant to operate.

When I first figured out that the runtime load was an issue I was able to get confirmation there was not inbuilt support beyond direct references here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33284 and I started looking for how to re-implement the existing work-around more properly.

I would prefer this to work as similar to a directly referenced RCL as possible, but I am not finding any information on if the bundles are meant to be referenced globally at all times or conditionally, I do not see any obvious way to get them to be added as an @import programmatically, and I have no idea what the implications of trying to manually create the _content folder from the bundle files found in the various \obj folders would be.

How this is really supposed to work in development and when publishing? Is what i am doing even close or is there some glaring issue I will be encountering down the road?

Comment: I assume you know where to find the library CSS files once they are built.  If not,  ask.  I think the answer to your question is there is no straight solution.  You can probably come up with a single bundled CSS file with some customization of the build process.  i.e. wait for the main build process to build the library CSS bundles and then pull them together into a single CSS.  You can also add or remove CSS files dynamically.  There's some code notes here - https://shauncurtis.github.io/posts/DynamicCss.html - not the finished article.

Comment: now I am scraping the individual library bundled css from the obj folders after the build that match "*obj\$BuildFolder\net5.0\scopedcss\projectbundle\*.css" to a seperate folder then adding a <link> for each item in that folder in a look in the _host... it works, but I really have no idea how close to the inbuilt functionality this is or if there would be possibility/value in getting it into the _content / @import pattern the built-in stuff uses.  If there is a better place to source the files from that will work in debug and deploy OR better ways of getting them included is what I am asking